# Hibernate suddenly slow and firing a lot queries

Tags: hibernate

I'm using Hibernate,MySQL,Tomcat.The application was running fine with usual number and speed of queries.Suddenly i can see now the page loading has become extremely slow.Lot of queries continuously getting fired.The logs are just scrolling over and not stopping with queries.Can anyone suggest/advice what should i do to see the reason and fix this problem

Tried cleaning maven, updating project, maven install, clean tomcat directory, multiple times but it's still same behaviour

Comment: My crystal ball is telling me the problem is on an even line of your code in one of the files, but that's as much as I can get with the provided information.

Comment: Looks like it was a peculiar behavior. After performing cleanup and build multiple times also restarting STS couple of times ; resolved the problem.I'm not sure which action out of the multiple attempts solved the problem.But there was no code change in JAVA /Spring for resolving it.